# Error "'str' object is not callable" when using property setter

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to use a property setter as below. I'm following the example here:
[How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work/17330273)

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self):
        self._funds = 0.00

    @property
    def funds(self):
        return self._funds

    @funds.setter
    def funds(self, value):
        self._funds = value
```

The getter works fine

```
>>> contact = Contact()
>>> contact.funds
0.0
```

but I'm missing something about the setter:

```
>>> contact.funds(1000.21)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1315, in __run
    compileflags, 1) in test.globs
  File "<doctest __main__.Contact[2]>", line 1, in <module>
    contact.funds(1000.21)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: contact.funds = 1000.21

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the `contact.funds = 1000.21` syntax. It will set it using `@funds.setter`.

I cannot reproduce your `'str' object is not callable` error, rather I get a `'float' object is not callable` error. More detail on how it is being run would be helpful for diagnosing that. Regardless, the reason is that `contact.funds` will give you back the value of `contact._funds`, which is not a callable object, hence the error.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question as to what he is doing wrong here

Comment: @APorter1031 While I thought the answer to the question was self-explanatory, I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @MoxieBall, sorry I was simplifying the code to boil it down to the simplest form. I was modifying the string before returning. I took out that and changed it to an int but never updated the error message. Thanks for providing the answer.

Answer (score 4):

[@MoxieBall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9801728/moxieball) and [@pavan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1770135/pavan) have already shown the syntax. I'll dive in a bit deeper to help explain what's going on.

The `@property` decorator exists precisely so you can get and set object fields via the convenient `x = object.field` and `object.field = value` syntax. So [@MarkIrvine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361629/mark-irvine), you've done everything correctly to enable your `contact.funds()` getter to become `contact.funds` and your `contact.funds(value)` setter to become `contact.funds = value`.

The confusion lies in the fact that the `@property` decorator re-defines the symbols in your contact objects. In other words, `contact.funds` *is* a [Descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#definition-and-introduction). Once you've applied the `@funds.setter` decorator to `def funds(self, value):`, the `funds` function no longer exists as you defined it. So `contact.funds(value)` first returns the `contact.funds` property, then tries to call it as if it were a function.

Hope that helps. =)

Comment: Thanks for the extra clarification.